# Java empty synchronized block

Tags: java, concurrency

Есть два потока: thread1 и thread2. Первый видит код:

```
synchronized(globalVar) {
    thread2.start();
    s = 1;
}
```

Второй поток ждёт лок по globalVar:

```
synchronized(globalVar) {
}
someVar = s;
```

[Считается](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/issues.pdf) (стр 14), что в данном случае пустой блок синхронизации гарантирует, что второй поток увидит значение **s**, присвоенное первым потоком.

Будет ли это верно для любого количества потоков и вообще, не лучше ли использовать ReentrantLock ?

Comment: А почему бы не следовать простому правилу: доступ к разделяемым переменным **необходимо** синхронизировать — и переписать код так:

    synchronized(globalVar) {
        someVar = s;
    }

?

Код в приведённой вами редакции будет скорее всего работать, но почему не воспользоваться правильным общим решением, а изобретать велосипед?

Comment: > доступ к разделяемым переменным необходимо синхронизировать 

@VladD, синхронизация это самый "тяжелый" способ.

Comment: @Nofate: По сравнению с чем? С запуском потока? Вряд ли. Если вам нужно _такое_ количество синхронизаций, что затраты становятся заметными, что-то с архитектурой не так.

Comment: @VladD, context-switching VS throughput/scalability - это целая философия :) подозреваю, что под "тяжелым" способом имелся ввиду exclusive lock, который дает synchronized

Comment: @Vladimir Kishlaly: Да, я так и подумал. Тут не только context switching, тут ещё и сброс кэша процессора, что довольно затратно.

На мой вкус, лучший подход к разделяемым переменным — не иметь их вовсе. Потоки должны изредка перебрасываться иммутабельными сообщениями à la Smalltalk. Концептуально ещё лучше вообще абстрагироваться от потоков, наподобие техники `Task` (`Future`) + `async/await`.

Comment: @VladD, если вы про future tasks и Lock.condition.await/ForkJoin.await, то уже есть

Comment: @Vladimir Kishlaly: нет, `await` в .NET качественно другая штука. Он не саспендит текущий поток в ожидании результата другого задания, а _превращает остаток метода в [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)_ и прикрепляет к заданию, результата которого надо дождаться.

В результате с низкоуровневой точки зрения async-метод как бы переключается в другой поток.

Comment: @VladD, любопытно. Похоже на [work stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilk#Work-stealing)

Comment: @Vladimir Kishlaly: угу, похоже. Это позволяет, например, не блокировать поток, ожидая чтения данных с диска или ответа сервера, таким образом количество потоков существенно падает. Плюс автоматический проброс исключений из других заданий.

Думаю, Java к следующей версии тоже подтянется, разработчики наконец-то снова взялись за клавиатуру. (С Scala уже, кстати, есть.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `s = 1;`

Если `s` - просто целочисленное поле, то для соблюдения `happens-before`, разумнее будет отказаться от синхронизации и объявить поле как `volatile` (если отсутствуют неатомарные обращения) или использовать тип `AtomicInteger` (если нужно обеспечивать атомарность доступа).

> Считается (стр 14), что в данном случае

не считается, а гарантируется